# Script to avoid rendering new elements loaded while scrolling?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser, crash

I am on a MacBook Pro M2 with Google Chrome. I am scrolling through a lot of elements in a web page. To be more specific, I am scrolling through a lot of Facebook profiles and I've noticed that after a while the page crashes saying "Aw, Snap". I've tried to increase the browser default cache size but that didn't fix the issue because it's not the problem. The issue could be in the structure limits of the Blink engine.
The new elements are added, and therefore rendered, while scrolling (lazy loading).
I thought: what if I prevent the new elements to be rendered?
Basically I would need to set:

```
element.style.display = 'none';
```

but I would need to do this before the element is added, otherwise if I do it after it would be still rendered.
So, I guess I would need to find the script that get the element from server and I would need to make the appropriate changes before it's added.

I also tried to remove the elements, thinking it could remove some of the "weight" but even though I am able to go futher with the scrolling it still crashes after a while.

```
var profiles = document.querySelectorAll('tagName');
for(var i=0;i<profiles.length;i++) {
profiles[i].remove();
}
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
 try{W.contentWindow.stop();} catch(e){}
```

NB: Where "W" is your frame ID, and needless to mention that you should call this just after the page has loaded.

From Mozilla...

> The window.stop() stops further resource loading in the current
> browsing context, equivalent to the stop button in the browser.
>
> Because of how scripts are executed, this method cannot interrupt its
> parent document's loading, but it will stop its images, new windows,
> and other still-loading objects.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/stop

Comment: That won't stop Facebook triggering **new** loads as the user scrolls. It just cancels in-progress loads.

Comment: But what I need to do is loading them without rendering (showing) them.

Comment: There are no such issues with Blink, any problems are most likely related to your system. When was the last time you cleaned your system up and scanned for malware thoroughly?